# 2-line label ggplot looks abnormal

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with complex 2-line axis label which contains formatting in first part of it.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Groups=c("A", "B"), Values = c(1,2))
label2 <- expression(paste(italic("The quick brown fox jumps over the\n lazy dog."), " Non-italic part of label"))
ggplot(df, aes(x = Groups, y = Values)) +  
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete("Labels", labels=c("Short label", label2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Result image doesn't look good (there are long empty space in the second line of the long label. So the label is oversized and the second line looks interrupted) and I can't find any way to resolve this problem.

I have also tried a more complicated expression, but separator did not positioned in the correct way.

```
label3 <- expression(paste(italic("The quick brown fox jumps over the"), paste(italic("lazy dog."), "Non-italic part of label"), sep = "\nSEP"))
```

Please share some ideas how to align second line correctly?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for supplying a reproducible example. Can you be more specific what "doens't look good"?

Comment: Roman, there are long empty space in the second line of the long label. So the label is oversized and the second line looks interrupted.

Comment: This issue isn't specifically related to `ggplot2`, try e.g. `plot(1, main = label2)`. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/JVqyio0tvhQ) for some answers, old ones though.